# Spritekit actions doesn't work on all devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, xcode9

I have spritekit scene with element that has actions:

https://scr.hu/dXryae

https://scr.hu/Gw3Ra5

I'm loading this scene, get the Overlay element and put every child of it in main scene of game. Everything were working fine till I tried to add some more features to it. This "features" cause that actions doesn't works. But this is not my problem. I came back to working copy and now it works different on different devices.

Test devices:

Iphone 5 10.3.3 - actions works

Iphone 7 Plus 11.0.2 - actions doesn't work

I've noticed that when I go to home screen of iOS and come back to game actions starts working.
I thought that it can be some cache problem but probably I tried every method of cleaning it.

I have no errors/warnings in xcode or in console.

Comment: you should post images in your question, not using a third party source. If the third party website is down this question becomes useless for anyone else.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are not managing the `isPaused` "correctly" (It is slightly "bugged" because Apple wants it to work in this buggy state)  Everytime you call isPaused, all children of that node also have this value flipped.  Certain events will cause it to flip also, and this can change depending on which version of iOS you are using.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon absolutely I have painstakingly discovered in iOS11 scenes sometimes get switched to paused errantly. I was typing my answer as you commented lol

Comment: @RonMyschuk, yup, i just disable the isPaused (override to do nothing) and set up my own variable to handle it

Comment: Ron Myschuk, I can't because of my low rank on Stackoverflow.

@Knight0fDragon, Thanks so much! I set isPaused to false on nodes that I was adding to scene and it works now. I don't know why it was set to true, because I wasn't using it.

Comment: @AlexanderWoźniak this is because Apple messes with the property without you knowing.  i tried explaining to them that they really should have a private facing pause variable for their stuff, and a public facing variable for the developers so that the developer can control when pausing occurs

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot...but I had a similar issue with my GameScene in iOS11.  However I was embedded in Messages so I am not sure it is the same issue, but I had the same symptoms. The Game Scene during the transition was getting paused automatically (but only in iOS11) after transitioning to the scene I ran `myScene.isPaused = false` and it fixed the issue, and had no adverse affects on iOS10